# Printing specific records - error message says String indices must be integer

Tags: python

I am struggling with a solution to my python code.
I want to print specific column_names (e.g. **Date**, **Open** etc...).  When I attempt to print the **Date** record I get an error `String indices must be integers`. Below is a copy of my code and the json file.
What am I missing?

```
import json, urllib
import quandl
url = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB.json?"
loaded = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(loaded)
for Date in data['dataset']['dataset_code']['Date']:
    print(Date)
```

JSON file

```
{
    "dataset": {
        "dataset_code": "FB", 
        "column_names": [
            "Date", 
            "Open", 
            "High", 
            "Low", 
            "Close", 
            "Volume", 
            "Ex-Dividend", 
            "Split Ratio", 
            "Adj. Open", 
            "Adj. High", 
            "Adj. Low", 
            "Adj. Close", 
            "Adj. Volume"
        ],
```

Comment: It appears that you have only provided part of the JSON file. It that is intentional then perhaps explain this within the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"dataset_code"` is a string.

When you do `data['dataset']['dataset_code']`, the result is `"FB"`. `"FB"` is a string, and therefore can't be indexed by another string. `data['dataset']['dataset_code']['Date']` is, in your example file, equivalent to `"FB"['Date']`. You can only use the `[]` operators on strings like `"FB"` if you're putting a number (an "`integer`") inside.

---

To do anything meaningful with this data, you might want to restructure the items into `dict`s. This will make the data a lot easier to work with. You could use this code to get a list of dicts:

```
cnames = data["dataset"]["column_names"]
entries = data["dataset"]["data"]
data_dict = [{c: entry[i] for i, c in enumerate(cnames)} for entry in entries]
```

Now, your data is in the form of

```
[
  {
    "Volume": 20184035.0, 
    "Ex-Dividend": 0.0, 
    "Adj. High": 125.835, 
    "Adj. Close": 125.15, 
    "Adj. Volume": 20184035.0, 
    "High": 125.835, 
    "Adj. Low": 124.6184, 
    "Adj. Open": 124.98, 
    "Low": 124.6184, 
    "Date": "2016-08-05", 
    "Close": 125.15, 
    "Split Ratio": 1.0, 
    "Open": 124.98
  }, 
  {
    "Volume": 21065974.0, 
    "Ex-Dividend": 0.0, 
    "Adj. High": 124.79, 
    "Adj. Close": 124.36, 
    "Adj. Volume": 21065974.0, 
    "High": 124.79, 
    "Adj. Low": 122.51, 
    "Adj. Open": 122.94, 
    "Low": 122.51, 
    "Date": "2016-08-04", 
    "Close": 124.36, 
    "Split Ratio": 1.0, 
    "Open": 122.94
  },
]
```

With this new format, selecting all values for an individual row is very simple. To get all the dates from the dataset, just use:

```
[x["Date"] for x in data2]
```

For convenience, wrap this in a function:

```
def get_all_values(key):
    return [x[key] for x in data2]
```

Now, you can use `get_all_values("Date")` or `get_all_values("Open")`.

Your full code would be:

```
import json, urllib
import quandl
url = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB.json?"
loaded = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(loaded)

cnames = data["dataset"]["column_names"]
entries = data["dataset"]["data"]
data2 = [{c: entry[i] for i, c in enumerate(cnames)} for entry in entries]


def get_all_values(key):
    return [x[key] for x in data2]

# Get all the dates from the dataset
for Date in get_all_values("Date"):
    print(Date)
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: I am trying to print the Date and Open from the JSON file.  JSON file looks like this:     u'2016-08-05', u'data': [[u'2016-08-05', 124.98, 125.835, 124.6184, 125.15, 20184035.0, 0.0, 1.0, 124.98, 125.835, 124.6184, 125.15, 20184035.0], [u'2016-08-04', 122.94, 124.79, 122.51, 124.36, 21065974.0, 0.0, 1.0, 122.94, 124.79, 122.51, 124.36, 21065974.0],

Comment: Ah. I needed the additional contents of the file. I'll revise my answer

Comment: I understand it now.  Thank you so much!!